# NLTK dialogue parsing in SPANISH giving error

Tags: parsing, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, spanish

I have been trying to parse a set of spanish dialogues using NLTK and it works on majority of dialogues, except a few of them. Fact is there are no new special characters or a special formatting difference in those. So, why are they not getting parsed I cannot figure this out.

This is one of the dialogues giving error:

```
Neville: Hola, alguien recuerda en qué fecha me casé? Don: Hablas en serio? Neville: Dead serio.\r\nEstamos de vacaciones, y Tina está enojada conmigo por algo. Tengo una extraña sospecha de que\r\nesto podría tener algoque ver con nuestro aniversario de boda, pero no tengo dónde comprobar.\r\nWyatt: Espera, le preguntaré a mi esposa. Don: Haha, alguien está en muchos problemas \r\nWyatt: Septiembre 17. Espero que recuerdes el año
```

This is the one working fine:

```
Sam: hey escuchaba a Rick decir algo Sam: no sé qué hacer :-/ Naomi: ¿quédijo?? Sam: él estaba\r\nhablando por teléfono con alguien Sam: no sé quién Sam: y él les estaba diciendo que él no era muy\r\nfeliz aquí Naomi: ¡malditasea! Sam: él estaba diciendo que no le gustaba ser mi compañera de cuarto\r\nNaomi: wow, ¿cómo te sientes al respecto? Sam: pensé que yo era un buen rommate Sam: y que\r\ntenemos un buen lugar Naomi: eso es verdadero hombre!\r\nNaomi: me encantaba vivir contigo antes de mudarme con mi novio Naomi: no sé por qué está\r\ndiciendo que Sam: ¿qué debo hacer?? Naomi: honestamente site molesta tanto deberías hablar con\r\nél Naomi: mira lo que está pasando Sam: no quiero entrar en ninguna clase de confrontación\r\naunque Sam: tal vez simplemente voy a dejarlo ir Sam: y ver cómo va en el futuro Naomi: estu\r\nelección Sam: si yo fuera a hablar con él y aclarar el aire
```